# Can one count the range between the start of target cell until the end of a target cell?

Tags: excel, range

My *data* looks as follows. The `1` in column `A` refers to new application while the `0` are *sub-acccesses* of the same application. I want to get the range of rows for one application.

```
     A      B
     IT     Dependency
1    1
2    0      App
3    0
4    0
5    0      File
6    0
7    1      
8    0
9    0
10   1      
11   0
12   0      App
```

I would like to count a range from `A1` to `A6`, starting afterwards again from `A7` to `A9`, etc..

Initially I thought to use `Countif` or `Lookup` but I could not usefully apply it.

**Output Expectation**

I would like to have the range (i.e. `A1:A6`) as output or `1` and `6`, so I can use it for other formulas (i.e. `concatenatemultiple`).

**Does Excel have a formula counting a varying range?**

Comment: What about subtotals?

Comment: @Dominique, I am not familiar with the `subtotals` function. How would you apply it here?

Comment: Can you show what the output will look like here? I know *what* the output is. Just not how you plan to organize it which may change the formula. Will it be a another column where the dependency count should be on same row as 1? Or will this be summarized in a table?

Comment: @urdearboy, I would like to use the formula `concatenatemultiple` where the output would need to be the same range just for column `B`. So, either I get I get a cell with the starting point and end point where I can refer to or I get the range but could change the letter to the column I am looking for. (I hope this is understandable). Eventually I want to concatenate all content from column B of the same application.

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe* in say D2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(A2=0,1+D1,0)
```

(Assumes labels are in Row**1**.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how would that help me to get the range between these two points?

Answer (score 0):

Need to use a combination of:
`MATCH`: To calculate the numbers of rows till next Application
`INDEX`: To define the range for each Application
`OFFSET`: To define the range for each Application *(Volatile)*
`IFERROR` and `COUNT`: to define the range of the last Application

*I seldom use OFFSET because it is volatile nevertheless the formula is there...*

Try this formula *(note that it uses `SUM` instead of`CONCATENATEMULTIPLE` since it is written in Excel 2013, but should also work in Excel 2016)*:

Using `INDEX`:

```
 =IF($A2<>1,"",  
 SUM(C2:INDEX($C2:$C$31,  
 IFERROR(MATCH(1,$A3:$A$31,0),  
 COUNT($A2:$A$31)))))
```

Using `OFFSET`:

```
=IF($A2<>1,"",
SUM(OFFSET($C2,0,0,
IFERROR(MATCH(1,$A3:$A$31,0),
COUNT($A2:$A$31)),1)))
```

[image]